Prediction games on directed acyclic graphs
I'm not familiar with game theory literature, so what I'm trying to study is probably well known, but I am not able to find a reference for this class of games.
Given a (rooted, finite) directed acyclic graph and two players, each player tries to predict the moves of the other. When reaching a node without outgoing edges, the game ends and the player which predicted the most moves wins.
I'm trying to study two kinds of games:

next move prediction: a player moves $m_i$ and predicts the move $m_{i+1}$;
conditional move prediction: a player moves $m_i$ and predicts the moves $m_{i+1}, m_{i+2}, \ldots, m_{i+j}$ (where $m_{i+j}$ is a first player move or is a terminating move); if the other player moves $m_{i+1}$, then the first player must move $m_{i+2}$, and so on.

Where can I find a review of games like the above ones?
